# including dependencies and source code of dependencies (recursively) in jar with Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I need to package all dependencies into a jar file, as well as the source codes of dependencies, including the source code of transitive dependencies (if the corresponding source code is in the repository).

Is there a way to force maven to do this?

the block below adds only the source code of direct dependencies, not transitive ones.

```
...
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>${artifactId}</artifactId>
      <version>${version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>${artifactId}</artifactId>
      <version>${version}</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
...
  </dependencies>
...

<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>
                    cf.teladi.Main
                  </mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: What is the reason you want to do that?

Comment: analysis by a static code analyzer.

Answer (score -1):

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>cf.teladi.Main</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

and you run it with

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

Comment: Does this include sources?!

Comment: it builds with the dependencies, but not with the source code of the dependencies.